# How to run template-engine-preview-3 together with iron-router package?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

How to run template-engine-preview-3 together with iron-router package ?

Git repository of [Iron-Router package](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/shark)  has branch called **shark**, which I believe should allow to use Iron-Router together with meteor's new template engine ( like template-engine-preview-3 )

.meteor/release :

```
template-engine-preview-3
```

smart.json:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "iron-router": {
      "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git",
      "branch": "shark"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

smart.lock:

```
  ...
  "iron-router": {
    "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git",
    "branch": "shark",
    "commit": "4e1ee0581d68bff422a915dacb0bd30eae10fe08"
  }
  ...
```

Additionally I run `mrt update`.
Meteor app is started with command : `meteor --release template-engine-preview-3`

Anyone was able to run successfully iron-router with new template engine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gadicohen has created a patch that works with `template-engine-preview-3`. You can test it by put this code in your `smart.json` file:

```
"iron-router": {
    "git": "https://github.com/gadicohen/iron-router",
    "branch": "dev"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't... Yet. ironRouter isn't yet ready to support the new template engine.

Follow https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/pull/238 for more details.

I guess you could fork ironrouter and plug that patch in if you really wanted it now.